Python pandas dataframe using apply to call function with list output
I am trying to apply a function to each element of a column of a pandas data frame. This function should return a list of strings. I would like to have each string in the list become its own column. Here is what I have been working with:
def parse_config(string):
    out = []
    pos = list()
    for x in re.finditer(pattern='\.',string=str(string)):
        pos.append(x.start())
    out.append(str(string)[0:pos[-2]])
    out.append(str(string)[pos[-2]+2:pos[-1]-1])
    out.append(str(string)[pos[-1]+1:][0:-1])
    out.append(str(string)[pos[-1]+1:][-1])
    return out

This function, given a string like 'abc.(e).ghi' will return ['abc','e','gh','i'].
I would like each of these list members to be placed in a column of the data frame.
I have tried
df[['a','b','c','d']]=df.apply(lambda x: parse_config(x['configuration']),axis=1)

with the hope new columns 'a','b','c','d' would be populated with the output of the function. There error I get is:
IndexError: list index out of range
Can someone help me understand what is wrong? I have done essentially the same thing with a function that outputs one scalar (directing output to new column) and that works fine.

The attempt you made with df.apply() was mostly correct, but you need to use result_type='expand' in the apply() method to directly expand the list to columns:
import pandas as pd
import re

data = {'configuration': ['abc.(e).ghi', 'test.(m).example', 'sample.(d).demo', 'failtest']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

def parse_config(string):
    try:
        pos = [x.start() for x in re.finditer(pattern='\.', string=str(string))]
        if len(pos) < 2:
            return [None, None, None, None]  
        out = []
        out.append(str(string)[0:pos[-2]])  
        out.append(str(string)[pos[-2]+2:pos[-1]-1])  
        out.append(str(string)[pos[-1]+1:][0:-1])  
        out.append(str(string)[pos[-1]+1:][-1])  
        return out
    except IndexError:  
        return [None, None, None, None]  

df[['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']] = df.apply(lambda x: parse_config(x['configuration']), axis=1, result_type='expand')

print(df)

which gives
      configuration       a     b       c     d
0       abc.(e).ghi     abc     e      gh     i
1  test.(m).example    test     m  exampl     e
2   sample.(d).demo  sample     d     dem     o
3          failtest    None  None    None  None

